# Scheduled SQL Server reports via mail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, email, report

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express, and my question: is there any way to create daily reports that will calculate space available for each database, and send that report to one specific email address? Format of report doesn't matter at all, how can I do that? Thanks for all advice

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Task Scheduler would be one way to schedule the task, but you'll need to use a different tool to send the email. You could likely use Powershell's [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: i am at square one, and looking for possibe solutions, i heard there is ssrs tool for my problem.... but im lost...

Answer (score 0):

The below is more to set you on the right path. you'll need to have a look at the below, understand it, adapt it for your requirements, and then use Task Scheduler to use it. I cannot/will not support it; it's up to you to be able to do that, and if you can't do that don't use it.

The below is a Powershell script that makes use of sqlcmd to get the data, and then uses `Send-MailMessage`. I didn't use `Invoke-sqlcmd` as I don't have installed at the office. I'm sure someone could show how to use that as well. You'll need to set the credentials/server settings for your mail server:

```
$Query = "
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'USE ?' + NCHAR(10) +
                             N'INSERT INTO ##Files(DatabaseName, DBFile, SizeMB, SpaceUsed)' + NCHAR(10) +
                             N'SELECT ''?'', [name] AS DBFile, Size, FILEPROPERTY(name,''SpaceUsed'') AS SpaceUsed' + NCHAR(10) +
                             N'FROM sys.database_files' + NCHAR(10) +
                             N'WHERE Type_desc = ''ROWS'';';

EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb @command1 = @SQL,
                        @precommand = N'CREATE TABLE ##Files(DatabaseName sysname, DBFile sysname, SizeMB int, SpaceUsed int);',
                        @postcommand = N'SELECT DatabaseName, SUM(SizeMB) AS Size, SUM(SpaceUsed) AS SpaceUsed, SUM(SizeMB - SpaceUsed) AS FreeSpace FROM ##Files GROUP BY DatabaseName; DROP TABLE ##Files;';"

$databases = sqlcmd -S YourSQLServer -E -d master -Q "$Query"  -s "," -W | Out-String
Write-Host $databases
Send-MailMessage -From "FromAddress@YourDomain.com" -To "ToAddress@YourDomain.com" -Subject "DB Space Remaining" -Body "$databases" -SmtpServer exchange
```

Note that this also made use of the **undocumented** procedure `sp_MSforeachdb`.